# com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl convert to string

Tags: xml, dom

I have an object of type

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl
```

containing an XML root element and structure beneath.

How can I retrieve the XML contents as a string from this?

Note that method `toString()` is available, but this has been implemented in a very rudimentary way, only reporting strings like `[root: null]`, hence only showing the root element name and not any further contents of this element.
In the javadoc this method is listed as "NON-DOM method for debugging convenience".

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little late, but if you're still looking for a solution, try this:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

where `node` is the DeferredElementImpl object. DeferredElementImpl implements the Node interface, so you should be able to use a transformer on it like with any other DOM node.

[Oracle: "Writing Out a DOM as an XML File"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT4.html)
[com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl API](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/swm/jdoc6/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/DeferredElementImpl.html)

Comment: Worth a try and anyway I awarded 1up because of having found this oldie amidst all Stack Overflow questions!

Answer (score 2):

I use this method for get String from `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl`

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) throws Exception {
    String data = "";
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof DeferredElementImpl) {
        DeferredElementImpl node = (DeferredElementImpl) child;
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        data = result.getWriter().toString();
    }
    return data;
}
```